# how can i get an end date for a row based an start date from another row

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerquery

I have a table with a inventory report with a list of items, location, date that item entered location:

For example in the table bellow:

- Item 1  goes into warehouse 1 at Jan 1st 2020
- stays in warehouse_1 in February 2020
- in March the item goes into wahrehouse_2 (which means it goes out of warehouse 1)

I need to build a summary of how many items in each warehouse for every month.
the challenge I'm facing is that i don't have end date column, so for February 2020 its blank while it should show item 1 is still in "warehouse_1"

For that i want to add a "end_date" column which takes the date from the next row of that item
(for row #1 the end date is 2020-03-01 when the item moves to "warehouse_2".

| item_id | date | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item_1 | 2020-01-01 | warehouse_1 |
| item_1 | 2020-03-01 | warehouse_2 |
| item_1 | 2020-08-01 | warehouse_1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate an `end_date` use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       lead(date) over (partition by item_id order by date) as end_date
from t;
```